# Multiple resize operations in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to combine some operations using ImageMagick's `magick` CLI, specifically two operations that resize/scale the image, a random one that does `-resize` and a bunch of other stuff, plus the answer from this question ([Average image color excluding transparency with Imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642910/average-image-color-excluding-transparency-with-imagemagick/53643008#53643008)).

The naive "mix everything together" doesn't work:

```
magick image -resize 10x10 ... -scale 1x1! -alpha off -format "%[pixel:u.p]\n" info:
```

...as I get an answer of "black", because this is obviously ignoring my image and using a blank image instead.

I've also tried with subimages (using `\( ... \)`) but that has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The following command works fine for me on ImageMagick 6.9.10.16 Q16. What is your ImageMagick version and what other commands do you need in the command line. You only show ...! What else is there? Also can you post your image? You cannot just put "image" in your command line. You have to specify the actual image file and possibly the path to it.

Input:

[image]

```
convert logo.png -transparent white -resize 50% -scale 1x1! -alpha off -format "%[pixel:u.p]" info:

srgb(100,82,99)
```

Same with IM 7.0.8.16 Q16 HDRI:

```
magick logo.png -transparent white -resize 50% -scale 1x1! -alpha off -format "%[pixel:u.p]" info:

srgb(100,81,99)
```

The slight difference is likely a difference from precision with IM 6 (non-hdri) and IM 7 (with hydra).

Comment: `image` was just an example, that command is obviously not complete. I'll add more details there